# Looping through an array within 'new'

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to test dynamic buttons for a child application using the ruby on rails gem Rubychy. This is the way it would be done statically:

```
keyboard = Rubychy::DataTypes::Keyboard.new(
  :to => 'myname',
  :hidden => false,
  :responses => [
    Rubychy::DataTypes::KeyboardResponse.new(
      type: "text",
      body: blah,
    ),
    Rubychy::DataTypes::KeyboardResponse.new(
      type: "text",
      body: blah1,
    )
  ]
)
```

The responses are predefined. I need to loop through an array and call `Rubychy::DataTypes::KeyboardResponse.new()` each time. While this is terribly incorrect, it shows what I need to loop.

I tried different ways to do this, and I've been caught up every time.

```
keyboard = Rubychy::DataTypes::Keyboard.new(
  :to => 'myname',
  :hidden => false,
  :responses => [
    parsed_response["values"].each do |val|
      Rubychy::DataTypes::KeyboardResponse.new(
        type: "text",
        body: val.name,
      )
    end
  ]
)
```

Can anyone assist with this?

Comment: `responses = parsed_response["values"].each do |val| ...... end` then `:responses => responses` - use a temporary variable.

Comment: @DaveSlutzkin Except that `x.each { ... }` returns `x`.

Comment: @muistooshort ...unless it was prematurely interrupted with `break y` :)

Comment: Ah yeah, sorry, `.map`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`Enumerable#map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-map):

> **map { |obj| block } → array**
>   [...]
>   Returns a new array with the results of running *block* once for every element in *enum*.

In your case:

```
parsed_response['values'].map do |val|
  Rubychy::DataTypes::KeyboardResponse.new(
     type: "text",
     body: val.name,
  )
end
```

which can be added to your code like this:

```
keyboard = Rubychy::DataTypes::Keyboard.new(
  :to => 'myname',
  :hidden => false,
  :responses => parsed_response["values"].map do |val|
    Rubychy::DataTypes::KeyboardResponse.new(
      type: "text",
      body: val.name,
    )
  end
)
```

or even:

```
to_response = ->(val) do
   Rubychy::DataTypes::KeyboardResponse.new(
     type: "text",
     body: val.name,
   )
end
keyboard = Rubychy::DataTypes::Keyboard.new(
  :to => 'myname',
  :hidden => false,
  :responses => parsed_response["values"].map(&to_response)
)
```

to make the logic clearer and the code less noisy.